# Add custom watermark to product image

Tags: magento-1.8, image

all. I'm trying to add custom watermark to product image with next code:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')
    ->init($_product, 'small_image')
    ->resize(174)
    ->watermark($imagefile);
```

but it still displays a product small image resized without any modification. Any ideas?

Comment: So I guess the build in watermark in System > Configuration > General: Design - Product Image Watermarks won't work for you?

Anyway. Could you be more specific on where you add this code?

Comment: yes, default watermark feature doesn't fit my needs. I have manufacturers logos, and i want to add watermark to products images. I insert this code to src of an image in products list. Like this: `<img height="174" width="174" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(174)->watermark($imagefile); ?> alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />`

Answer (score 2):

finnaly, i figured out, how to put custom watermark to product image:

```
public function getWatermarkedImage(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product){

    $product->load('media_gallery');
    if ($product->getImage() && $product->getImage() != 'no_selection'){
        $basePath = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaPath();
        $image = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_image');
        $image->setDestinationSubdir('watermarks');

        if(!file_exists($basePath . '/'. $product->getImage())) {
            return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . '/catalog/product/placeholder/default/no-image.png';
        }
        $image->setBaseFile($product->getImage());
        //$processor = new Varien_Image($image->getBaseFile());
        //$image->setImageProcessor($processor);

        if (!file_exists($image->getNewFile())){

            $stamp = Mage::getModel('amshopby/value')->load($product->getManufacturer(),'option_id')->getImgMedium();
            $logoStamp = 'logo.png';
            if (!file_exists($basePath . '/watermark/default/' . $stamp)){
                if(!file_exists($basePath . '/watermark/default/')){
                    mkdir($basePath . '/watermark/default/', 0744, true);
                }
                copy(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/amshopby/' . $stamp, $basePath . '/watermark/default/' . $stamp);
            }
            try{

                $image->setWidth(600)->setKeepAspectRatio(true)->resize();
                $image->setWatermarkImageOpacity(100);
                if (file_exists($basePath . '/watermark/default/' . $logoStamp)){
                    $image->setWatermark($logoStamp, 'top-left', null, 170, 93, 100);
                }
                $image->setWatermark($stamp, 'bottom-right', null, 200, 129, 100);
                $image->saveFile();
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return $image->getUrl();


    }
    else return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . '/catalog/product/placeholder/default/no-image.png';

}
```